# wordpress mysql query not able to create view with concat and like

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Trying to create view with following query

```
SELECT * from wp_posts AS vender 
LEFT OUTER
JOIN wp_postmeta AS vender_campaign ON vender_campaign.meta_key = 'vender' 
  AND vender_campaign.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%"',vender.ID,'"%')
WHERE vender.post_status = 'publish' AND vender.post_type = 'vender'
```

But getting error:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci, IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci, IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

But if I execute this query in phpMyAdmin window it works fine.

Any idea what is the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that wp_posts and wp_postmeta have different encodings, utf8mb4_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_general_ci.

The query works because you can see the result of those tables as a join but you can not create a view with different encodings.

I would change the encoding of one of those two tables to match the other one.

EDIT: I guess you can also format your query in a way in which you convert the encoding of one of the texts from one of the tables to the encoding of the other one (but if you are able to I will unify encodings nonetheless)
see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: I just cheked and both tables have same encodings, DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Tried sinlge table without join select * from wp_postmeta AS vender_campaign where vender_campaign.meta_key = 'vender' AND vender_campaign.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%"',360,'"%') still getting same error

Comment: I guess the key to solve your problem is finding where that utf8mb4_general_ci (note the general) comes from.
Maybe the string you are entering on the concat is getting it, if the tables are not... but again, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks Miquel for heading me to right direction, I found that field and resolved that issue by changing it as "CAST(vender_campaign.meta_value AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)"